# Filter results of API call by formatting JSON

Tags: python, json, rest

I have the following code that issues an API call that returns info about every listing on a marketplace. I have removed the clientId and clientSecret for privacy.

```
"""
import base64
import requests


clientId = "fakeId"
clientSecret = "fakeSecret"
clientData = f"{clientId}:{clientSecret}"
encodedData = str(base64.b64encode(clientData.encode("utf-8")), "utf-8")
authorizationHeaderString = f"Basic {encodedData}"

import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.skinport.com/v1/items", params={
    "app_id": 730,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "tradable": 0
}).json()

print(r)
"""
```

Here is a sample from the output:

```
"""
{'market_hash_name': 'USP-S | Whiteout (Factory New)', 'currency': 'EUR', 'suggested_price': 153.1, 'item_page': 'https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-factory-new', 'market_page': 'https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S', 'min_price': 171.03, 'max_price': 232.16, 'mean_price': 197.13, 'median_price': 194.25, 'quantity': 7, 'created_at': 1633294586, 'updated_at': 1693686845}, {'market_hash_name': 'USP-S | Whiteout (Field-Tested)', 'currency': 'EUR', 'suggested_price': 22.18, 'item_page': 'https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-field-tested', 'market_page': 'https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S', 'min_price': 19.25, 'max_price': 175, 'mean_price': 41.53, 'median_price': 36.55, 'quantity': 61, 'created_at': 1632899292, 'updated_at': 1693686845}, {'market_hash_name': 'USP-S | Whiteout (Minimal Wear)', 'currency': 'EUR', 'suggested_price': 32.96, 'item_page': 'https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-minimal-wear', 'market_page': 'https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S', 'min_price': 39.64, 'max_price': 185, 'mean_price': 77.81, 'median_price': 69.99, 'quantity': 61, 'created_at': 1632921139, 'updated_at': 1693686845}, {'market_hash_name': 'USP-S | Whiteout (Well-Worn)', 'currency': 'EUR', 'suggested_price': 17.62, 'item_page': 'https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-well-worn', 'market_page': 'https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S', 'min_price': 19.79, 'max_price': 32, 'mean_price': 25.9, 'median_price': 25.9, 'quantity': 2, 'created_at': 1632976633, 'updated_at': 1693686845}, {'market_hash_name': 'Valeria Phoenix Pin', 'currency': 'EUR', 'suggested_price': 51.74, 'item_page': 'https://skinport.com/item/valeria-phoenix-pin', 'market_page': 'https://skinport.com/market?item=Valeria%20Phoenix%20Pin&cat=Collectible', 'min_price': 53.95, 'max_price': 80, 'mean_price': 63.66, 'median_price': 59.99, 'quantity': 14, 'created_at': 1535988295, 'updated_at': 1693686845}, 
"""
```

I'm relatively unfamiliar with JSON formatting, so my question is, what is the best way to filter through the returned data so that I can store info about items that meet certain conditions. For example, the program returns thousands upon thousands of lines of info about listings, but I only care about the listings for a certain market_hash_name or a certain min_price, or both.

I'm sure there is a way to do this by editing the API call, but I'd prefer to do it by simply formatting the returned JSON.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension to filter your result. In variable `r` you have (I'm assuming) list of dictionaries:

```py
r = [
    {
        "market_hash_name": "USP-S | Whiteout (Factory New)",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "suggested_price": 153.1,
        "item_page": "https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-factory-new",
        "market_page": "https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S",
        "min_price": 171.03,
        "max_price": 232.16,
        "mean_price": 197.13,
        "median_price": 194.25,
        "quantity": 7,
        "created_at": 1633294586,
        "updated_at": 1693686845,
    },
    {
        "market_hash_name": "USP-S | Whiteout (Field-Tested)",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "suggested_price": 22.18,
        "item_page": "https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-field-tested",
        "market_page": "https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S",
        "min_price": 19.25,
        "max_price": 175,
        "mean_price": 41.53,
        "median_price": 36.55,
        "quantity": 61,
        "created_at": 1632899292,
        "updated_at": 1693686845,
    },
    {
        "market_hash_name": "USP-S | Whiteout (Minimal Wear)",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "suggested_price": 32.96,
        "item_page": "https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-minimal-wear",
        "market_page": "https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S",
        "min_price": 39.64,
        "max_price": 185,
        "mean_price": 77.81,
        "median_price": 69.99,
        "quantity": 61,
        "created_at": 1632921139,
        "updated_at": 1693686845,
    },
    {
        "market_hash_name": "USP-S | Whiteout (Well-Worn)",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "suggested_price": 17.62,
        "item_page": "https://skinport.com/item/usp-s-whiteout-well-worn",
        "market_page": "https://skinport.com/market?item=Whiteout&cat=Pistol&type=USP-S",
        "min_price": 19.79,
        "max_price": 32,
        "mean_price": 25.9,
        "median_price": 25.9,
        "quantity": 2,
        "created_at": 1632976633,
        "updated_at": 1693686845,
    },
    {
        "market_hash_name": "Valeria Phoenix Pin",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "suggested_price": 51.74,
        "item_page": "https://skinport.com/item/valeria-phoenix-pin",
        "market_page": "https://skinport.com/market?item=Valeria%20Phoenix%20Pin&cat=Collectible",
        "min_price": 53.95,
        "max_price": 80,
        "mean_price": 63.66,
        "median_price": 59.99,
        "quantity": 14,
        "created_at": 1535988295,
        "updated_at": 1693686845,
    },
]

market_hash_name = "Valeria Phoenix Pin"
min_price = 50

out = [
    dct
    for dct in r
    if dct["market_hash_name"] == market_hash_name and dct["min_price"] >= min_price
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "market_hash_name": "Valeria Phoenix Pin",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "suggested_price": 51.74,
        "item_page": "https://skinport.com/item/valeria-phoenix-pin",
        "market_page": "https://skinport.com/market?item=Valeria%20Phoenix%20Pin&cat=Collectible",
        "min_price": 53.95,
        "max_price": 80,
        "mean_price": 63.66,
        "median_price": 59.99,
        "quantity": 14,
        "created_at": 1535988295,
        "updated_at": 1693686845,
    }
]
```